# Laravel 4 exception handling - same code works in 1 case and not in 2 other cases

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to handle a few exceptions in Laravel 4, and the same snippet of code works for one of them but not for the others.

I declared an Exceptions.php file that I added to my composer.json.

In Exceptions.php, I declared the following:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
Class NotAllowedException extends Exception {};
```

The following handler, in Exceptions.php, works properly:

```
// snippet 1
App::error(function(NotAllowedException $e, $code, $needed)
{
return Response::make(View::make('special.error')->with('error', array('headline' => 'Not Allowed',
                          'description' =>'<p>Your user has not enough privileges to perform the requested operation.</p>')), 401);

});
```

When I try to do the same to handle HttpNotFoundExceptions and ModelNotFoundExceptions, the following 2 snippets which are copies of the first do not work and yield an **Undefined variable: error** error.

```
// snippet 2
App::error(function(ModelNotFoundException $e)
{
return Response::make(View::make('special.error')->with('error', array('headline' =>'Not Found',
                'description' => '<p>It seems you have tried to access a page that does not exist.</p>')), 404);
});


// snippet 3
App::error(function(NotFoundHttpException $e)
{
return Response::make(View::make('special.error')->with('error', array('headline' =>'Not Found',
                'description' => '<p>It seems you have tried to access a page that does not exist.</p>')), 404);
});
```

I was only able to make the NotFoundHttpException work by putting this into global.php:

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
return Response::make(View::make('special.error')->with('error', array('headline' =>'Not Found',
                'description' => '<p>It seems you have tried to access a page that does not exist.</p>')), 404);
});
```

But I do not know why it works if I put it there and it does not work if I put it in Exceptions.php.

Trying to put snippets 2 and 3 in global.php yield in both case an Internal Server error.

To recap, **Questions**:

- I think I am following the ModelNotFoundException handling as per Laravel4's documentation; what What am I doing wrong / how to make it work?
- why does the App::missing work only if I put it in global.php ? I fear that I might be missing something important about Laravel's inner workings.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can shed some light on those 2 issues

Comment: It could be `namespace` collision.

Comment: Hi, namespaces are something new to me; what would you suggest to do?

Comment: Ok, I moved snippet 2 - ModelNotFoundException - to global.php and now it works. I still do not fathom why it doesn't work when in Exceptions.php, while snippet 1 does.
I'd have liked to change snippet 2, return to "throw new NotFoundHttpException" but again I can't make it work :-)

Comment: Which one is working and where it is and where those that not working ?